# python skip unittest based on attribute

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

We use the python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html) module and [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for testing to benefit from each of their strengths. Nose gives us the ability to skip certain tests on the command line using the `nose.plugins.attrib`, ex:

```
import nose.plugins.attrib

@nose.plugins.attrib.attr('slow')
class Testdiskio(unittest.TestCase):
    r'slow running disk intensive tests'
```

Then from command line we use **python setup.py nosetests -A "not slow"** to run our quick tests. In those circumstances we want to run everything, including the disk intensive tests, we use: **python setup.py nosetests**

But python's unittest has no such option. We've tried to adapt the `unittest.skipIf` decorator, but there's not mechanism to pass options from the command line to conditionally test the attribute in `skipIf`.

Just wondering if anyone else has come up with a solution to selectively running/skipping tests against the python unittest module from the command line?

Comment: Last release of nose happened in 2015 and the project is pretty much abandoned. Pytest is the most advanced and popular test framework these days. Definitely consider switching.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and I'll check up on it...but my question was about the python builtin unittest module.